# Using nested resources

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'd like to have nested resources with eg. category, posts, posts.

Urls would look like mysite.com/#/1/posts or mysite.com/#/1/posts/123

The 1 being category id, although I'd be interested in changing that into a friendly slug.

My initial code is something like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('category', {path:'/:category_id'}, function(){
        this.resource('posts',{path:'/posts'}, function(){
            this.resource('post', {path:'/:post_id'});
        });
    });
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params){
       return Post.find({category:params.category_id});
   }
})
```

Now I'm wondering if these :model_id markers are optional in the router, and thus /posts would actually give category_id == 'posts'. I'm also wondering how it would work if I were to simply use category as a simpler url query and how that fits in to ember.